# How to write values from SimpleXML array in input field

Tags: php, html, arrays, simplexml

I have a simpleXML array called `$tags` that contains a list of tags which I would like to use for the default value of an input field when loading a page.

**My XML (example):**

```
Array ( [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => tag1 ) 
        [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object ( [0] => tag2 ) 
)
```

**My HTML (for demonstration):**

```
<input type="text" 
    class="form-control optional sel2" id="tags" name="tags" 
    value="<?php echo $tags; ?>" 
/>
```

The above is just for demonstration as I don't know what is the correct approach for this. How can I get the values from the array set as the default value for the input field so that in the above example this would show "`tag1,tag2`"?

Comment: general idea: loop the values of xml and store inside an array, then echo `implode` on the markup.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to convert the array of SimpleXMLElements into an array of strings. Then you can use it in `implode()`.

```
echo implode(',', array_map(function($tag) {
    return (string) $tag;
}, $tags));
```

---

Come to think of it, I doubt you need to map the array. Using `SimpleXMLElement` in `implode()` should implicitly convert them to strings so this should suffice...

```
echo implode(',', $tags);
```

Demo here ~ https://eval.in/187582

Comment: Thanks a lot for this - that's exactly what I was looking for. Will accept as soon as I can. :)